# How to avoid 'implicit' calling of a one-parameter constructor in std::pair

Tags: c++, stl

The original problem was how to work with `std::map<std::wstring, std::wstring> >` in a secure way because equal types of the key and the value are extremely error-prone. So I decided to create a simple wrapper for the value:

```
    struct ComponentName
    {
      std::wstring name;

      // I want to prohibit any implicit string-ComponentName conversions!!!
      explicit ComponentName(const std::wstring& _name) : name(_name)
      {
      }

      bool operator<(const ComponentName& item_to_compare) const
      {
        return name < item_to_compare.name;
      }
    };

    typedef std::map<std::wstring, ComponentName> component_names_map;
```

But the following code works well!

```
component_names_map component_names;
// Are you sure that ComponentName's constructor cannot be called implicitly? ;)
component_names_map::value_type a_pair = std::make_pair(L"Foo", L"Bar");
```

It works because the `std::pair<std::wstring, ComponentName>` copy constructor explicitly uses the string contructor of the ComponentName to assign the `std::pair<std::wstring, std::wstring>` instance. It's an absolutely legal operation. However it looks as an 'implicit' call of the ComponentName constructor.

So I know the reason of the problem, but how can I avoid this 'implicit' `wstring-ComponentName` conversion?
The simplest way is to not declare the string constructor, but it makes ComponentName initialization inconvenient.

Comment: +1 for a well presented question.

Comment: I'm guessing here, but I imagine the constructor for `std::pair` explicitly invokes the single-argument constructor of its contained types.  Check the source to be sure.

Comment: I don't think you *can* prevent someone from writing an implict-conversion wrapper for your explicit constructor...

Comment: Oli, I've already written about this. The question is how to declare a ComponentName string constructor to avoid this conversion or find an alternative way to create ComponentName from a string in a convenient way.

Comment: Maybe you might write a factory function for your type.

Comment: to Kerrek SB: I'm almost sure that it cannot be avoided if I use constructors. Another alternative is to create a static fabric method, but I'd like to find at least one more solution.

Comment: Note that the code that the user *should have* written, namely `value_type a_pair(L"Foo", L"Bar");`, is indeed correctly forbidden. C++ isn't about enforcing absolutes, but rather to make it hard to write wrong code and easy to write right code. I think your design is adequate in that respect.

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov: I can also write a wrapper to your factory method. The moral is, you cannot really stop anyone who's bent on being a pain. But you don't have to; that's not the purpose of a library writer. You should concentrate on making the code easy to use correctly.

Comment: What you really want is the opposite of `friend` - a sort of `enemy` keyword perhaps?

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB, your class seems perfectly fine: it does not allow implicit conversion. The fact that `pair` hides the explicit conversion from the user should not be your concern. All other solutions you could come up with could be wrapped in a similar way. By the way, there is no assignment involved in your example, only copy construction.

Comment: The issue is not with your class, but with the implementations of `std::pair`. As of @KerrekSB example: `value_type a_pair(L"foo", L"bar")` will not trigger a compiler error, because the implementation of `pair` (all I know of) will perform explicit conversion of the pairwise elements rather than the implicit conversion mentioned in the standard. See the links in my answer for a longer discussion.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Not quite. `value_type a_pair(L"foo", L"bar");` **will** trigger the error, as expected, because `value_type` is a concrete type. There's no deduction going on.

Comment: Make sure this is all worth it. At the moment I cannot see why equal key and value types are evil. Could elaborate on that a bit, so I could understand the motivation for this? At the moment it sounds a bit like premature obfuscation, but maybe I'm just blind.

Comment: @KerrekSB: My bad, I was thinking on the conversion from a different pair type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you can legally do this by adding a partial specialisation of `std::pair` for your type:

```
namespace std {
    template <typename T>
    struct pair<T,ComponentName> {
       typedef T first_type;
       typedef ComponentName second_type;

       T first;
       ComponentName second;
       // The rest of the pair members:
       // ....
       // Any trick you like to make it fail with assignment/construction from 
       // pair<std::wstring, std::wstring>
    };
}
```

Justification:

§ 17.6.4.2.1 sets out the basic rules for specialisations in the `std` namespace:

> "A program may add a template specialization for any standard library
>   template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a
>   user-defined type and the specialization meets the standard library
>   requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>   prohibited"

I can't see any explicit prohibition that would rule this particular case out, provided you filled out the rest of the class, within the bounds of § 20.3 .

---

Alternative, possibly legal approach:

Specialize `std::is_constructible<ComponentName, std::wstring>` such that `value` is false. This is listed as a requirement of both the assignment operator and the copy constructor for `std::pair`s of different types. I can't see any prohibitions from a quick scan of this either, but I can't find anything saying that implementations are *required* to check the requirements.

Comment: A bit monstrous, but correct solution with no runtime penalties. Thank you! As for me, I've decided to use the fabric method. It works slower a little because requires 1 copying in my case, but it's simpler.

Comment: I think on this one I'd just take the hit on the `map<T,T>` problem personally

Comment: @DmitrySapelnikov: I'm sure you have your reasons. From the outside it is hard to judge, though. To me, implementing a factory just to avoid this one corner case looks like a massive loss of elegance. You have to weigh whether it's worth it, and whether there really is such a huge problem with people causing an implicit construction in error.

Comment: @KerrekSB - agreed. Nothing you do can ever completely stop somebody passing the "wrong" value in somewhere. `map[L"foo"] = L"bar"; cout << map[L"bar"];` is always possible to write one way or another, even with a factory thrown in.

Answer (score 4):

The problem (in C++03) is that most standard library implementations are not really standard conforming. In particular, the standard states that when a `std::pair<T,U>` is constructed from a different `std::pair<V,W>` the members are constructed by implicit conversions. The problem is that it is actually really hard (if even possible) to restrict that conversion in the implementation of the templated `pair` constructor, so current implementations perform *explicit* conversion of the arguments:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct pair {
    // ...
    template <typename V, typename W>
    pair( pair<V,W> const & p ) : first( p.first ), second( p.second ) {} 
};
```

I actually wrote a blog post about this particular case [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/i-decided-to-start-writing-few-months.html), and for the sake of it I tried to provide the appropriate conversion constructors [here](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/improving-conversions-of-stdpair-s.html), but the solution is not standard compliant (i.e. it has a different signature than those required by the standard).

Note: In C++11 (§20.3.2p12-14) this implicit conversion is also forbidden (From FDIS):

```
template<class U, class V> pair(pair<U, V>&& p);
```

> Requires: is_constructible::value is true and is_constructible::value is true.
>
> Effects: The constructor initializes first with std::forward(p.first) and second with std::forward(p.second).
>
> Remark: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless U is implicitly convertible to first_type and V is implicitly convertible to second_type.

The equivalent restrictions are present in p9-11 for the equivalent for `template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);` (in case the types are not *movable*)

Comment: Interestingly the wording of n3290 seems to be stronger than the wording you quoted on your blog. It now states *"This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless `U` is implicitly convertible to `first_type` and `V` is implicitly convertible to `second_type`"* which would seem to make this behaviour a defect as it has most definitely participated in overload resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Simple:

```
enum FromString { fromString };

ComponentName( FromString, std::wstring const& aName)
    : name( aName )
{}
```

Comment: That's indeed simple, but it's also ugly and confusing. Sadly, I don't have a better idea either. `:(`