# Excluding std::pair constructors that use explicit construction

Tags: c++, c++11, sfinae

Following on from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135555/how-to-avoid-implicit-calling-of-a-one-parameter-contructor-in-stdpair/8137176#8137176), it seems these constructors:

```
template<class U, class V> pair(pair<U, V>&& p); 
template<class U, class V> pair(const pair<U, V>& p);
```

are forbidden from participating in overload resolution when they would require an explicit conversion.

From C++11 (§20.3.2, n3290):

> Remark: This constructor shall not participate in overload resolution unless U is implicitly convertible to first_type and V is implicitly convertible to second_type.

An interesting [SFINAE workaround](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/improving-conversions-of-stdpair-s.html) has been suggested, but this digresses from the text of the standard.

How can a conforming implementation possibly exclude this from overload resolution, short of some special internal compiler magic? I.e. can an implementation do this and can I duplicate it for my own type perhaps? There doesn't seem to be anyway of conforming with this! Is it a hangover from the removal of concepts from C++11?

I did wonder about using a private constructor to do the SFINAE part and delegating from the public constructor, but it doesn't look like constructor delegation participates in SFINAE in such a way as to make that work.

Comment: "How can a conforming implementation possibly exclude this from overload resolution?" Magic?

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - that does seem to be the only way to do it - I was hoping it wasn't the case as it's pretty ugly to be making large chunks of standard headers into magic and not something I can imagine being high on the list of priorities for implementations to fix.

Comment: Did you even have a look at how some do it? gcc seems to use enable_if on is_convertible.

Comment: @PlasmaHH - you're right, it turns out I looked in the wrong header when I looked at this. http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40925#c3 does imply it was intended to be handled via concepts originally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but this digresses from the text of the standard

An implementation is allowed to add default arguments to any non-virtual library member function. This seems to permit precisely this kind of SFINAE tricks.

Comment: interesting - I'd not seen that spelled out before - where is it specified? It also seems to contradict what the linked blog posting states.

Comment: In 17.6.5.5/2 (according to my copy of n3290).

Comment: that solves that one for me quite nicely - I half wonder if it's a new relaxation of the rules or not, but that's probably wondering a bit far off the original question now.

Comment: @awoodland : It's not new, C++98 permitted the same (as well as default template arguments on template classes); this is why it's always been illegal to forward-declare any standard library identifiers.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing two pieces of information:

1. gcc uses this:

   ```
   template<class _U1, class _U2, class = typename
                  std::enable_if<std::is_convertible<_U1, _T1>::value
                                 && std::is_convertible<_U2, _T2>::value>::type>
           pair(_U1&& __x, _U2&& __y)
           : first(std::forward<_U1>(__x)), second(std::forward<_U2>(__y)) { }
   ```

   The trick seems to be in the default for the anonymous `class` template parameter. I'd not seen that before and [this implementation](http://definedbehavior.blogspot.com/2011/07/improving-conversions-of-stdpair-s.html) didn't use that.
2. I missed that gcc actually implemented this.

Comment: Default template parameters for non-class templates is a very recent feature. Using that limits portability to 1 or 2 compilers. Even fewer six months ago. :-)